# Add space between letter and special character

Tags: visual-studio-2015, crystal-reports

I want to display the Company name and contact number seperated by a space. But when report is printed, the space between `Information` and `+(92345)` is ignored and prints `XYZ Technologies+(92345) 123 4567`

Report design view:

[image]

Printed report:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If Company Name and Contact Number are separate fields, you can drag both of them into a new Text Object and manually type a space between them.

Otherwise create a new Formula object to do it for you:

```
REPLACE(<yourOriginalFieldHere>,"+"," +")
```